# How to read lucene 4.0 index with java?

Tags: java, lucene

I've used Lucene 4.0 and I can not find the "term()" method in IndexReader class with Lucene version 4.0. How to read the index? Please help. I want to know the contents  (Terms, Term Frequency and so on) of the index file.Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bet is that you need to use http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/AtomicReader.html, it have all needed methods.

Also take a look here - http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexReader.html - it explain you how to create needed readers.